# Generic Class for only specific types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class Wood:

```
public class Wood<A>{
    public A element;

    public Wood(A element)
    {
        this.elem = elem;
    }
}
```

and an interface Prec:

```
public interface Prec<A>{
    public boolean prec(A a);
}
```

I want to a new class, which takes all the attributes from Wood and extends it with some new methods. These methods require the objects of type A, to have implemented the interface Prec. Therefore I thought, that this code works:

```
public class SortedWood<A extends Prec> extends Wood<A>
{

}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
SortedWood.java:1: error: constructor Wood<A#2> cannot be applied to given types: 
public class SortedWood<A extends Prec> extetends Wood<A>
  required: A#1
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where A#1,A#2 are type-variables:
    A#1 extends Prec declared in class SortedWood
    A#2 extends Object declared in class Wood
```

What's the problem here, and how can I solve it?

Comment: No, this isn't allowed.
error: > expected (after SortedWood<A)

Comment: I'm getting a different compile-time error - there isn't a no-arg constructor for `Wood` so it's blowing up on that.

Comment: I added a no-arg constructor for Wood, and now the code seems to work. Thanks. Any explanation, why the no-arg constructor is necessary?. Because an object of type Wood should always be initialized with an element. I don't need/want a no-arg constructor.

Comment: `<A extends Prec>` has a raw type. It should be `<A extends Prec<?>>` or `<B, A extends Prec<B>>`. (This is aside from the compilation error you have encountered.)

Comment: @JonnyHenly The `extends` keyword is used with both superclasses and interfaces in generic bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JLS §8.8.9:

> It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.

This means, if your parent class doesn't have a default constructor, but your child class *does*, then you have a compilation error on your hands.

Let's remove the generics and look at it like this:

```
public class Parent {

    private int age;
    public Parent(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
    }
}
```

The above code won't compile since `Parent` doesn't have a default or no-arg constructor in it.  The child class can't invoke the parent's constructor since it doesn't exist.

If we fix it so that it *does* reference `super`...

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
}
```

...then the compiler is happy once more.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Once I called super(elem), it worked.

Comment: This answer is misleadingly phrased. Constructors aren't inherited, and there's nothing that requires subclass constructors to look anything like the superclass constructor. The only requirement is that every subclass constructor must have a call to some `super` or other as its first statement, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Better, but it's still fine for the subclass to have a default constructor. It just has to have a static value to upcall with.